# Blank page when watching a Cypress test video

Tags: cypress

When I'm running tests using Cypress, the screenshots are made fine but the videos are not recorded. All I see is this:

[image]

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using version 6.0.0 of cypres or lower with chrome 87. This problem is resolved by the cypress developers in versions 6.0.1 and above.
[Changelog for 6.0.1](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#6-0-1)